# How to display one or more images, depends of selected dropdown choice?

Tags: javascript

I want to display one or more images, depending on the dropdown choice, with javascript.

For first choice I want to display one image, but for second choice I want to display two images, first one plus new. I found many answers how to display different images based on dropdown choice but I couldn't find an answer how to display img + img if user choose that dropdown option.

By the way, I don't have many experience with javascript but that is what I am looking for. It sounds simple but not for me... :-) Thanks!

This is how I was thinking that js code should looks, but doesn't work. I am sure you can tell me why and what is right solution... Thanks to everyone! And before that I was define var...

```js
var ring1 = document.getElementById('ring1');
var ring2 = document.getElementById('ring2');
var ring3 = document.getElementById('ring3');
var ring4 = document.getElementById('ring4');
var ring5 = document.getElementById('ring5');
var ring6 = document.getElementById('ring6');
var ring1img = document.getElementById('ring1img');
var ring2img = document.getElementById('ring2img');
var ring3img = document.getElementById('ring3img');
var ring4img = document.getElementById('ring4img');
var ring5img = document.getElementById('ring5img');
var ring6img = document.getElementById('ring6img');

function selectedOption() {
  if (ring1.value == 1) {
    ring1img.style.display = 'block';
    ring2img.style.display = 'none';
    ring3img.style.display = 'none';
    ring4img.style.display = 'none';
    ring5img.style.display = 'none';
    ring6img.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" action="">

  <h1>Ring Schedule Display System</h1>

  <div class="tab">Club info:
    <p><input id="club" placeholder="Name of club..." input type="text"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="City..." input type="text"></p>
    <select number="rings" id="rings" onChange="selectedOption()">
      <option hidden>Choose number of rings...</option>
      <option value="1" id="ring1">1 ring</option>
      <option value="2" id="ring2">2 rings</option>
      <option value="3" id="ring3">3 rings</option>
      <option value="4" id="ring4">4 rings</option>
      <option value="5" id="ring5">5 rings</option>
      <option value="6" id="ring6">6 rings</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="tab">Welcome <b><span id="clubresult" style="font-size: 25px" ></span></b><br>
  <h2 align="center">Cat Show <b><span id="cityresult" style="font-size: 25px;"></span></b></h2>
  <img src="iconRing1.png" alt="ring1" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring1img">
  <img src="iconRing2.png" alt="ring2" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring2img">
  <img src="iconRing3.png" alt="ring3" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring3img">
  <img src="iconRing4.png" alt="ring4" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring4img">
  <img src="iconRing5.png" alt="ring5" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring5img">
  <img src="iconRing6.png" alt="ring6" style="width: 20%; display: " id="ring6img">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to use "if" and "else" statement but no results...

Comment: Can you post your attempt as code into the question?

Comment: Yes, I am trying that... Sorry :-) I am looking how to do that here, I am new here...

Comment: @Magnus Just copy/paste the code into your question and then mark it as code.

Comment: There is piece of code and you can see what I need... For each choice want to show images depends of selected number. For first choice show first image, for second choice show first AND second image...

Comment: @Magnus please post your javascript file with function "selectedOption" too

Comment: You need some javascript to accomplish this. Can't do with plain html

Comment: I just put a code, just first part of it, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) i'm able to iterate through all of the *rings* and first remove the `.show` class if it exists on that particular ring. Then if the `forEach` index is lower than the value taken from the selected option, we can then add the `.show` class again.

This works because by default, each `.ring` has `display:none` set in CSS. But `.show` overrides this with `display:inline-block`.

```js
const ringSelector = document.getElementById('ringSelect');
const rings = document.querySelectorAll('.ringImg');
ringSelector.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange(e) {
  const amount = +e.target.value;
  rings.forEach((ring, i) => {
    ring.classList.remove('show');
    if (i < amount) {
      ring.classList.add('show');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.ringImg {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select id="ringSelect">
  <option hidden>Choose number of rings...</option>
  <option value="1">1 ring</option>
  <option value="2">2 rings</option>
  <option value="3">3 rings</option>
  <option value="4">4 rings</option>
  <option value="5">5 rings</option>
  <option value="6">6 rings</option>
</select>

<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you see, I have different images, not all images are same. I need them to be diferent. This works fine but if I am using only one image, same image... I need to have one diferent image for each choice from dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thank you all who answer on my question. @ksav was help me to find solution and now it works.

```
<style>
.ringImg {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ringImg2 {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ringImg3 {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ringImg4 {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ringImg5 {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ringImg6 {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<select id="ringSelect">
  <option hidden>Choose number of rings...</option>
  <option value="1">1 ring</option>
  <option value="2">2 rings</option>
  <option value="3">3 rings</option>
  <option value="4">4 rings</option>
  <option value="5">5 rings</option>
  <option value="6">6 rings</option>
</select>

<div class="ringImg"></div>
<div class="ringImg2"></div>
<div class="ringImg3"></div>
<div class="ringImg4"></div>
<div class="ringImg5"></div>
<div class="ringImg6"></div>

<script>
const ringSelector = document.getElementById('ringSelect');
const rings = document.querySelectorAll('.ringImg, .ringImg2, .ringImg3, .ringImg4, .ringImg5, .ringImg6');
ringSelector.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange(e) {
  const amount = +e.target.value;
  rings.forEach((ring, i) => {
    ring.classList.remove('show');
    if (i < amount) {
      ring.classList.add('show');
    }
  })
}
</script>
```